# Cannot Use java.sql.Date for returning a List<Object>?

Tags: java, spring

I have a Java Entity class with the following Date import:

```
import java.sql.Date;
```

the Entity is declaring a Date. In my repository, I have the following Query:

```
@Query("SELECT new Filmographer (f.name, f.startDate) FROM Filmographers f")
public List<Filmographer> getFilmographers();
```

However, when I attempt to build this file, I receive the following error:

```
Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class [Filmographer]
Expected arguments are: java.lang.String, java.util.Date [ SELECT 
new Filmographer(f.name, f.startDate) FROM Filmographers f]
```

If I remove the date altogether from both the entity and repository, it works fine.

Can someone explain to me why Java appears to be picking my date declaration for me and plausibly ignoring my **java.sql.Date** import?

**UPDATE**: Pojo added upon request:

```
package com.example.Filmographer;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="Filmographers")
public class Filmographer implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Filmographer() {}

    public Filmographer(
        String name,
        Date startDate
    ) {
        this.name = name;
        this.startDate = startDate;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="filmographerid")
    private int filmographerId;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="startDate")
    private Date startDate;

    public int getFilmographerId() {
        return filmographerId;
    }

    public void setFilmographerId(int filmographerId) {
        this.filmographerId = filmographerId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Date getStartDate() {
        return startDate;
    }

    public void setStartDate(Date startDate) {
        this.startDate = startDate;
    }

}
```

Comment: share your pojo please

Comment: Good question, can you save Dog in List<Animal> where Dog extends Animal? :)

Why do you get error for 2 argument constructor while you have 3 arguments in constructor???

Comment: @amitmah this java.sql.Date is working fine for someone else on the team. When I change it to util.Date, it crashes their functionality. What I'm asking is why this is an issue and second, a possible solution to the issue.

Comment: @AmerQarabsa I have updated with POJO. Thank you.

Comment: You are trying to call a constructor with 2 arguments, while you only have a constructor with 3 arguments...

Comment: @M.Deinum apologies for wasting your time. In the actual entity, the constructor does not contain the id, it's the correct amount (name, date) and still is an issue. thank you.

Comment: Hi @MindsectTeam The error you mentioned "Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class [Filmographer]
Expected arguments are: java.lang.String, java.util.Date [ SELECT 
new Filmographer(f.name, f.startDate) FROM Filmographers f] " seems to be related to constructor arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Expected arguments are: java.lang.String, **java.util.Date***

> As you can see that the function requires the data type to be of
>   java.util.Date and not of java.sql .

Now one of the main reason of Spring being lightweight is the POJO classes and if a class is referencing to sql , it would not be a POJO class and hence the error.

**Now you can search for a similar method which takes the sql.Date . But this method is not built to handle the data type java.sql.Date.**

Answer (score 2):

As the error is trying to tell you, you need `java.util.Date`, not `sql`.

Comment: I had the same thought. But why not sql.Date, java.time or Joda? What I'm not understanding is why a blank entity with only one Date declaration (java.sql.Date) is requesting java.util.Date. Seems odd.

Comment: @MindsectTeam: Because that's what Spring has been configured to use.  In particular, POJO's aren't supposed to reference SQL classes.

Comment: Interesting, thank you for that insight. If removing the java.sql.Date reference would break another portion of the code, is there any way to co-exist with this java.sql.Date reference for my situation if possible?

Comment: You need to fix your POJOs to actually be POJOs.

Comment: Aside from fixing the POJO, in a real world environment, is there any way to  overcome this issue if an sql.Date has already been implemented throughout the application?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Spring, it has everything to do with how hibernate works. Next to that your domain/pojo/... shouldn't rely on the `javax.sql` classes, which would mean that now your whole code base is coupled to SQL (now imagine you want to move the MongoDB or something else....).

Comment: Hi @SLaks, since java.sql.Date extends java.util.Date , sql date IS A util date